# Android Service Exchange always crashs

Tags: android, service, crash, synchronization, accountmanager

I'm getting a crash always when I install or uninstall an app that use Sync Service, like Facebook, whatsup, etc.

"Unfortunately, Exchange Services has stopped."

I don't know why, but it just happens for some devices, in my case all of then are Android 4.4.2.
First I thought it's my app's fault, but it doesn't make sense once I uninstall my app and the problem continues happening for others apps.

Do you know something about it?

Thank you.

```
02-07 14:31:49.864    3015-3015/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.email.provider
02-07 14:31:49.864    3015-3015/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.exchange, PID: 3015
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.exchange.Exchange: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://com.google.android.email.provider
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4347)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://com.google.android.email.provider
        at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:1352)
        at com.android.exchange.Exchange.onCreate(Exchange.java:34)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what was happening!

The problem occurs by device when there are sync accounts registered, but the Exchange Service cannot find any application to answer the URI, in my case it was "content://com.google.android.email.provider", to fix it I checked my disable applications and there was it, my default email application was disable. I just enable it again and the problem never occurs again.

Comment: Just moments ago found I'm in a similar position and I anticipate a similar outcome based on what I've read here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Apps > ALL> Exchange Services > Clear Cache` and try opening it. When it opens, check once.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem. now I’m using a good app called Mailwise. it’s a free email app, very convenient for businesses, you can easily set up multiple email accounts, and it works great with Exchange.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syntomo.email&hl=en